# ООП. Отношение один-к-одному? Какой шаблон использовать?

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, архитектура, шаблоны, solid

Типичная ситуация. Для примера возмём такую же типичную машину.

У машины есть колёса(содержит), машина придаёт вращение колёсам(влияет), колёса перемещают машину(влияют).

Как правильно составить такую композицию с точки зрения ооп, может GRASP или SOLID?
Какой шаблон проектирования тут использовать?

Не могу чего-то догнать. Постоянно с этим трудности.

Comment: Наивное размышление: а должны ли колеса влиять на машину? Ведь она может передвигаться и без вращения (очень тупой пример, но на торможении колеса могут не крутиться, а машина все еще будет перемещаться по инерции). Кажется, что пусть колеса крутятся, а уж какое реально было перемещение пусть определяетс сама "машина". (я сам с этим всегда туплю, пусть умные люди рассудят).

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что колеса перемещают машину, машина перемещается сама, а состояние в котором находятся колеса является одним из параметров для расчета этого перемещения.

Comment: @yolosora, это детали реализации. Можно так сделать, можно по другому. Речь ведь не о машине, об отношении один-к-одному.

Comment: @МистерФикс в моем понимание **влияют** в том смысле как описано в вопросе это достаточно важный аспект с точки зрения архитектуры, грубо говоря колесо может сделать что-то вроде `owner.Move();`

Comment: @yolosora, если это предложение, то опишите, его пожалуйста, более подробно.

Comment: А пробовали рассматривать колесо как часть машины, при этом, машина может менять состояние колеса (поворачивать, набирать обороты, тормозить), но сама машина не знает как перемещаться в пространстве, за это отвечает третий элемент - сервис "физика"?

Comment: @test123, очень интересно. Написали бы в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опишу на примере "машина-колёса". Чем такой подход (где: либо машина решает как ей двигаться, либо колесо решает как двигаться машине), лично мне, кажется нелогичным:

- Если процесс движения сложен, более того, зависим от процессов движения других машин (или просто зависим от других объектов) - класс машины, либо класс колеса, обязан содержать огромное количество информации, выходящей за рамки самой модели машины/колеса. Зачем машине знать о всех машинах в округе? Зачем колесу знать о всех объектах в округе? (ямах, кочках, камней и прочих вещей, что так или иначе способно влиять на траекторию перемещения). Обычно, это считают избыточной информацией, а класс такой машины - нельзя назвать моделью. (Потому что это больше чем модель)

Например, есть [замечательный подход (MVC)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller), который предлагает отделить машину и её колёса от процесса перемещения. Машина содержит только то что делает её машиной - двигатель, колёса, руль и куча, свойственных машине, элементов, которые необходимо учитывать для движения машины в пространстве.

Контроллер же (в нашем случае - это "физика", то самое, что рассчитывает движение, на основании текущих состояний машины, её элементов, колёс, параметров и состояния колёс), при необходимости, может знать о мире, в котором располагается эта самая машина, и рассчитывать движение всех машин в этом мире, тем самым, учитывать взаимодействие машин друг с другом.

В контексте вашего примера:

> У машины есть колёса(содержит), машина придаёт вращение колёсам(влияет), колёса перемещают машину(влияют).

Я бы не стал давать машине возможность влиять на себя (или влиять на колёса, которые будут менять состояние машины), потому что это монолитная архитектура, где сама машина знает обо всём. С использованием сервиса/службы можно учитывать как движение машины в рамках физики (машина рассматривается как материальная точка), так и в рамках динамики (каждый элемент машины является частью машины, отсюда, машина является системой частиц, которые взаимодействуют между собой) - чувствуете, как уровень сложности возможных расчётов возрос? (а значит уменьшилась жёсткость архитектуры)

Comment: Это лучший ответ, на данный момент. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В ваших рассуждениях есть несколько моментов, которые хотелось бы прокомментировать.

> Какой шаблон проектирования тут использовать?

А зачем тут использовать какой-то шаблон?

Шаблоны проектирования - это набор архитектурных конструкций, призванных помочь в решении типовых задач. Они не являются обязательными к применению и уж совершенно точно не нужно пихать их везде, где только можно.

> может GRASP или SOLID?

А может KISS? Эти замечательные наборы букв конечно замечательны, и принципы, скрывающиеся за этими аббревиатурами действительно хороши. Но в контексте вашего вопроса они звучат как из анекдота "Фары протер, по колесу постучал, а машина все равно не заводится". Почитайте Роберта Мартина например, он эти принципы хорошо раскрывает.

Что касается ооп (п - проектирования). Довольно сложно, да и, прямо скажем, бессмысленно, пытаться нарисовать диаграмму классов для взятого с потолка примера. Для начала нужно определиться с решаемыми задачами, потом, в соответствии с ними, ограничить модель, выделить акторов, прорисовать и оптимизировать связи и т.д.

Главный вопрос к вашей постановке задачи - "для чего"? Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Задачу взаимного влияния друг на друга двух объектов.

Comment: Обычно считаются, что хорошо когда связи односторонние, то есть клиент->служба.

Comment: @МистерФикс KISS - это такой же архитектурный принцип, как и составляющие SOLID и GRASP. Мало того, Буковки SLI из SOLID, например, являются просто развитием KISS с углублением в конкретику. Связи должны отражать нужную детализацию модели предметной области, не более и не менее.Задача взаимного влияния объектов в принципе не решаема без контекста, четко определенных моделей и(!) понимания конечной цели. В зависимости от контекста, описанная вами модель может быть описана принципиально разными диаграммами классов.

Comment: @МистерФикс я всего лишь пытаюсь донести до вас мысль, что вопрос ваш достаточно абсурден. Скорее всего связано это с плохим пониманием принципов и задач объектно ориентированного проектирования. Плохого в этом ничего нет, при условии, что есть желание учиться и развиваться, но, к сожалению, вы предпочитаете обижаться и вставать в позу, увы.

Comment: вы бы лучше предложили решение, которым в такой ситуации воспользовались бы вы. Речь идёт о двунаправленной ассоциации, если вы не поняли.

Comment: @МистерФикс я, по моему, достаточно четко описал в ответе и комментариях, что вот конкретно в вашей постановке задачи решения могут быть очень разные вплоть до полной несовместимости друг с другом. Сама постановка вопроса крайне аморфна и без контекста делать какие либо предположения - это тыкать пальцем в небо - авось угадаешь.

Comment: @МистерФикс в двунаправленной ассоциации (точнее в двух разных ассоциациях) нет ничего криминального, если она оправдана в рамках решаемых задач и принятой модели. Но определить для конкретно вашей задачи, оправдана ли она и корректна ли модель, без знания задачи и предметной области - невозможно в принципе.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72102/discussion-on-answer-by-rjhdby--------).